# ActiveMQ montoring using a JMX console -jConsole

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

how to see the message which was consumed by a consumer in ActiveMQ JMS using a JMX console -jConsole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
to do this you can browse topics `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Topic.YourTopicName`  or for Queue `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Queue.YourQueueName`  by using jconsole or visualVM, this is possible by  Advisory Message http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html and you need to enable this in the broker config by adding this :

```
    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <!--  http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html -->
            <policyEntry topic=">" advisoryForConsumed="true" />
            <policyEntry queue=">" advisoryForConsumed="true" />
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

code to browse advisory messages.

```
        Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getMessageDeliveredAdvisoryTopic(destination);
        Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getMessageDiscardedAdvisoryTopic(destination);
        Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getMessageConsumedAdvisoryTopic(destination);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(advisoryDestination);
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);

        public void onMessage(Message msg){
            String messageId =   msg.getJMSMessageID();
            String orignalMessageId =   msg.getStringProperty(org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.MSG_PROPERTY_MESSAGE_ID);
            if (msg instanceof ActiveMQMessage){
                try {
                     ActiveMQMessage aMsg =  (ActiveMQMessage)msg;
                     ConsumerInfo consumerInfo = (ConsumerInfo) aMsg.getDataStructure();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    log.error("Failed to process message: " + msg);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi hassen, could you please let me know what is the field which will show the message that was consumed by the consumer and the message id? And what message that was  not consumed by the consumer

Comment: the problem is that `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed` is a topic and if there is no subscriptions messages will be lost, the solution if you need to browse them by jconsole is the duplicate messages from this topic to a custom queue with camel or AMQ interceptors, or you use some code to browse them. to see discarded messages you can subscribe to `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDiscarded.Topic` . i update the response with some code.

Comment: Can we view Queue Data i.e payload, sent to consumer by producer in 1 server and payload consumed by the consumer in other server?

Comment: you mean by servers 2 ActiveMQ in different hosts ?

Comment: yes,2 ActiveMQ in different hosts 1 is producing and other is consuming using Queue mechanism

Comment: can you explain how AMQ produces message ? you meant it is only accepting producers and forwards to second AMQ ? if yes i think it is the same mechanism of advisory and each one will duplicate messages to advisory.

Comment: Suppose we have 2 server 1 server is used to receive message which is receiving payload from external as SOAP now we need to send the payload to 2nd server as JMS Queue Point - point mechanism now i need to see if the payload is being send to 2nd server or it's getting consumed by 2nd server or not? and which payload is not getting picked

Comment: you can connect to the 2nd AMQ to advisory topics to be notified if the message is consumed by answer code using   ` Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getMessageConsumedAdvisoryTopic(destination);`  you can visit the advisory AMQ doc to choose which topic to listen to depends on your needs

Comment: Depending on your needs, if you don't want to open jmx port or do more configs for security with AdvisorySupport you can create a consumer with different secured protocols already opened and your consumer will be notified when a message is sent to destination but with jmx you need to browse messages. You can analyse available methods for each one to to decide which one fits more with your needs.